# While I am installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I get the following error

Tags: system-installation

Today I downloaded Ubuntu for my desktop but when I tried to install it, I've got the following error message:

```
[Errno 5] - Input/output error
```

I tried everything to install it on desktop, but nothing works.

[image]

Comment: At what step in the process do you get Input/Output error ?

Comment: 12.04 is End of Life. Don't install it. Use either 16.04 (LTS, like 12.04) or 17.10.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you provided already answers the most likely cause of this problem: The installation medium which you're installing from, or the hard drive you want to install to, seems to be faulty. That's why you get the "Input/output error".

If you burn the image to a CD or DVD, then make sure to have it check for errors after completion. There is usually a checkbox / option for this, so you can verify that it burned the disc correctly. Test your hard drive for errors, too.